# How to exclude the total row information from VSQL output

Tags: vertica, vsql

I am using VSQL to extract data from a table in CSV format using this command:

> vsql -h [host_address] -d [db_name] -u [user_name] -w [password] -A -F , -t -f script_to_extract_data.sql -o output.csv

However, it outputs column headers, data rows AND an extra row that indicates the total number of rows in the table like this:

```
Geography,Product,Campaign,VariableName,Outlet,Creative,Period,VariableValue
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-03,24.06
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-08,67.17
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-17,404.67
(3 rows)
```

If I exclude the `-t` option, it'll output just the data like this:

```
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-03,24.06
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-08,67.17
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-17,404.67
```

I would like the column headers AND the data, but not the total row number like this:

```
Geography,Product,Campaign,VariableName,Outlet,Creative,Period,VariableValue
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-03,24.06
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-08,67.17
Geo_00000,Product,BABY,web_sales,Total,Total,2016-10-17,404.67
```

From reading through [VSQL commandline options](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/vsql/CommandLineOptions.htm), I don't think I have a way to restrict the total number of rows not show?? Anyone who is experienced with using VSQL via commandline could help me out, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented way to do this.

You could just inject a select into your script though to print out the header while leaving tuples-only on.

```
\t
\a
\f ,
\o output.csv
select 'Geography', 'Product', 'Campaign', 'VariableName', 'Outlet', 'Creative', 'Period', 'VariableValue';

select Geography, Product, Campaign, VariableName, Outlet, Creative, Period, VariableValue
from mytable;
\o
```

And I guess if it really, really bothers you to list the fields twice, you could use a variable.

```
\set fields Geography,Product,Campaign,VariableName,Outlet,Creative,Period,VariableValue
```

Then reference `:fields` in both queries (just use `'` around it for the header list).  In this case, the header list would just need to be a string, and the delimiter would have to be a `,` since it would also be used in sql. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you! This hack of adding `SELECT 'Geography, ....` before is a great workaround! :)

Comment: No problem. You can also just list out the fields in strings which might be better in case you decide to change the delimiter in the future. `select 'Geography','Product' ...` In fact I do like that better so I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without `-t` add `-P footer=off`...this will give you headers without the footer like you want.

```
vsql -h [host_address] -p [port] -d [db_name] -u [user_name] -w [password] -AP footer=off -F , -f script_to_extract_data.sql -o output.csv
```